# Why does fputs() not append a trailing new line?

Tags: c

or equivalently,

#### Why does `puts()` append a trailing new line?

---

When outputting a string, two similar functions may be used: `fputs()` and `puts()`.

`puts()` automatically adds a new line to the end when outputting, but `fputs()` doesn't.

Is there any reason behind this inconsistency? I mean, calling `printf(fmtstr, ...)` and `fprintf(stdout, fmtstr, ...)` have the same behavior. Why shouldn't it be the case for `puts(str)` and `fputs(str, stdout)` as well?

Is it because of backwards compatibility, or is there a good reason why they are implemented this way?

Comment: I don't know ... maybe there's a paralellism between `gets()` and `fgets()`

Comment: From [the `fputs` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fputs.3.html): "**`fputs()`** writes the string s to stream, without its terminating null byte (`'\0'`)." In other words, it's not specified to add a newline.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I know it is not specified to add a newline. I'm asking *why* it is not specified to do so, while `puts()` is specified to do so.

Comment: @ace For that you have to ask the inventors of the functions. Looking over the "good" reference sites (like [this one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) or the [POSIX reference site](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)) I could find no rationale behind it, I could check the C11 specification, but I doubt I'll find anything there. I would just put it down to "historical facts".

Comment: That is a good question for you to ask and I'm sure there's an historical reason for that behaviour, even if it was a human mistake made by some engineer.  However, the documentation is very explicitly about this. A better question would be, "why this kind of things happen?" but then it will be beyond the scope of SO.

Comment: I always missed print(fmt, ...) and prerr(fmt, ...) that are versions of fprintf(stdout) and fprintf(stderr) that put \n automatically and are easy to read and type and show debug info in active development phase. Good news we can define macros/statics in prefix.h for that, though it's not very convenient to always keep it around. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

`puts` writes to the standard output, which "everyone knows" is your line-oriented terminal, while `fputs` can write to a file, which does not have that connotation.  In particular, it is a more convenient method than combining `strlen` and `fwrite`.

The same relationship held between `gets` (now deprecated) and `fgets`.

Answer (score 2):

`gets()` and `puts()` were supposed to be used for simple input/output from the terminal whereas `fgets()` and `fputs()` are more general and provide finer control: you can specify the stream and they do not perform any implicit linefeed handling.

It is a pity `gets()` was badly specified and paved the way for so many buffer overflows.  It was finally removed from the latest C Standard.